# Filtering for IPs that send a packets of a certain length

Tags: wireshark, netflix

I'm trying to find all the IP addresses that netflix uses to deliver content, as the lists I've found online do not include many of the servers that I've observed sending content. Is there any way in wireshark to list all ip addresses that send packets of a certain length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this filter in the "filter" textbox on the top left of wireshark's interface:

```
frame.len==434
```

or

```
frame.len>=120
```

Those are obviously just random numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to only show a single entry for each ip address with this?

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean. If I got it right, you'll find it under Statistics->IP addresses after you applied the above filter.